# ```sudo iw dev``` shows mysterious virtual p2p interface on WLAN alongside normal interface

Tags: networking, wireless

```
phy#0
    Unnamed/non-netdev interface
        wdev 0x3
        addr 9c:fc:e8:b6:61:43
        type P2P-device
        txpower 0.00 dBm
    Interface wlp5s0
        ifindex 3
        wdev 0x1
        addr 9c:fc:e8:b6:61:42
        ssid myhomewifi
        type managed
        channel 149 (5745 MHz), width: 80 MHz, center1: 5775 MHz
        txpower 22.00 dBm
        multicast TXQ:
            qsz-byt qsz-pkt flows   drops   marks   overlmt hashcol tx-bytes    tx-packets
            0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0       0
```

There are somehow 2 interfaces, one in p2p mode, with different MAC addresses differing by one. What is causing this? My best guess is a direct connection to a printer or something, but I really don't know and am curious to find out. (I discovered this doing an unrelated thing)

Intel ax200 wifi in a m.2 e slot

Answer (score 0):

1. Hi there pal, almost every network interface today got few similar macs that represent other connections from the same device.
2. "MAC" Acronyms is "Media Access Control" well its "In the name" you have macs for every component that needs to talk with another one and if to be more specific, on "layer 2" the data link layer.
3. There are bluetooth macs wifi macs lan macs and so on, every component that needs to talk on layer 2 got a mac address.
4. The change of the last digits on the mac address is pointing that this is the same device.
5. As a rule the first six digits on mac address (x) xx:xx:xx:yy:yy:yy representing the company of the device, and the last six digits (y) representing the specific model of the device.
6. There are alot of reasons to for two macs from the same device like:

   - router with 2.4G and 5G networks.
   - router cable connection could have another mac.
   - the same could happen with more devices like old computer, game consoles and more.
   - there are alot more examples.
7. You can check the specific device company by running the mac address on https://macvendors.com/.
8. On your specific case its really look like one mac is for wifi connection and the other one is to peer to peer connection.
9. **Remarks:**

   - a mac address a uniq address and only used by one device.
   - today you have the option to use a "Random" mac address for privacy reasons for more information you can look at: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/wifi-mac-randomization.
   - you can find more information about the "5 layers" network model at: https://microchipdeveloper.com/tcpip:tcp-ip-five-layer-model.
   - example for printers peer to peer use https://www.extremetech.com/computing/51460-peertopeer-network-print-sharing

hope that was what you are looking for pal, there are alot more information out there.

Comment: I'm well aware what a MAC address is. I'm just curious why the 2 interfaces, the mac addresses being different was simply a note about them. Specifically, I'm wondering what in the system is creating a peer to peer connection. Also, this is on the same radio, there no wired one on this physical device.

Comment: well like i said, almost all the devices got few macs it could be for other services, it could even be the same radio (2.4 or 5) but not on the same channel. so its not really on the same radio, the channels are for human eye but its really 2.4XXXX 2.4XXXY and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same today, and after finding only this reference I figured out that NetworkManager created this. Stopping that daemon will also make the p2p interface disappear.